# Application is not launching. Cant find error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

My problem is that after I launch my app on emulator, it writes "unfortunately, appname has stopped". Eclipse doesnt show that there are any mistakes. I know I can somehow fix them using LogCat, but unfortunately Im totally new to eclipse and Im not sure how exactly to do it. So tell me plese what are my mistakes, and how can I fix them.

Logcat

```
03-15 07:18:55.620: D/AndroidRuntime(795): Shutting down VM
03-15 07:18:55.620: W/dalvikvm(795): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aa4ba8)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Process: com.gosha.bux, PID: 795
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gosha.bux/com.gosha.bux.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.gosha.bux.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  ... 11 more
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Process: com.gosha.bux, PID: 795
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gosha.bux/com.gosha.bux.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.gosha.bux.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-15 07:18:55.700: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  ... 11 more
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gosha.bux"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:debuggable="true"
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.gosha.bux.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Main

```
package com.gosha.bux;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int counter;
Button first;
TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    first = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    t= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    counter = 0;
    first.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    counter = counter+1;
    t.setText("heeey"+counter);
        }
    }) ;

}}
```

Comment: change type of `first` to ImageButton.

Comment: can you please add xml of this activity? so i can find error

Answer (score 2):

```
ComponentInfo{com.gosha.bux/com.gosha.bux.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

Solution 1:
Replace Button with ImageButton

```
ImageButton first = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Solution 2:
In your Layout change ImageButton with Button.

Comment: Yep. Either make this switch or change your layout to use a `Button` instead of `ImageButton`

Answer (score 1):

If you want `ImageButton` then change-

```
ImageButton first;
first = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

If you want simple Button then change-

`ImageButton` into `Button` in your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ImageButton first = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

If this doesnt work try to refresh your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gosha.bux/com.gosha.bux.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

suggests that you're casting an `ImageButton` to a `Button`. Is it possible that your `R.id.button1` is of type `ImageButton`?

You'd have to use

```
ImageButton first = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
  Button first;
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
first = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

to

```
ImageButton first;
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
first = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```